# python - aggregate data in nested list structure

Tags: python, list, lambda, aggregation

**I have a list with nested sub-list with the following structure**

```
in_data = 
 [
   [
     ['name', 'name_1'],  
     ['item_B', '2'], 
     ['item_C', '3'], 
     ['item_D', '4']
   ],
   [
     ['name', 'name_2'], 
     ['item_B', '5'], 
     ['item_A', '2']
   ],
   [
     ['name', 'name_3'], 
     ['item_B', '6'], 
     ['item_C', '7']
   ]
]
```

I am trying to collect all data in `in_data` and make a *unique list* that contains sub-lists, one for all the *"headers"*/ *names* and one for each item + values in the correct order.
So the information is preserved but in a different data-structure.

**I want to achieve this list**:

```
res_list = 
[
  ['name', ' name_1', ' name_2', 'name_3'], 
  ['item_B', '2', '5', '6'], 
  ['item_C', '3','-', '7'], 
  ['item_D', '4','-', '-'], 
  ['item_A', '-','2', '-'] 
]
```

I am trying to do it in the most pythonic way. I tried with for loops and also map() + lambda but no succeess.

would be the easy way?

Comment: *. I tried with for loops and also map() + lambda* - you need to post those attempts

Comment: What's with the *name* *vs.* *Skill* elements? The most *Python*ic way would probably be using list comprehensions.

Comment: why `'Skill'` word should be skipped/ignored?

Comment: i'd recommend rethinking this structure. dictionaries seem to make much more sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections
in_data = [[['name', 'name_1'], ['item_B', '2'], ['item_C', '3'], ['item_D', '4']], [['Skill', 'name_2'], ['item_B', '5'], ['item_A', '2']], [['Skill', 'name_3'], ['item_B', '6'], ['item_C', '7']]]
d = [list(zip(['name', *b[0][1:]], i)) for b in in_data for i in b[1:]]
new_d = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for i in d:
   new_d[dict(i)['name']][i[-1][0]] = i[-1][-1]

all_names = list({i for b in new_d.values() for i in b})[::-1]
result = [['name', *all_names], *[[a, *[b.get(k, '-') for k in all_names]] for a, b in new_d.items()]]
```

Output:

```
[['name', 'name_1', 'name_2', 'name_3'], 
 ['item_B', '2', '5', '6'], 
 ['item_C', '3', '-', '7'], 
 ['item_D', '4', '-', '-'], 
 ['item_A', '-', '2', '-']]
```

Answer (score 2):

The optimized approach (powered by composite dict keys `(<skill name>, <column name>)` and `dict.get` method):

```
header = ['names']
names = set()
d = {}

for lst in in_data:
    col_name = lst[0][-1]
    header.append(col_name)
    for name, val in lst[1:]:
        names.add(name)
        d[name, col_name] = val

res = [[n, *[d.get((n, h), '-') for h in header[1:]]] for n in names]
res.insert(0, header)
print(res)
```

The output:

```
[['names', 'name_1', 'name_2', 'name_3'],
 ['item_C', '3', '-', '7'],
 ['item_D', '4', '-', '-'],
 ['item_B', '2', '5', '6'],
 ['item_A', '-', '2', '-']]
```

Comment: @PM2Ring, that's Ok